# Align Commandlink in PageblockSEction?

Tags: visualforce

I've been playing with STYLE attributes and I haven't been able to get this commandlink centred with the rest of the fields in a PageBlockSection.

What am I missing?

![This is the screenshot]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pEjc.png

```
       <apex:commandLink onclick="window.open('/apex/ManageProperty_POC?id={!idcode}', 'blank'); return false;" >
         {!op.Property_Name_String__c}
        </apex:CommandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution - as a work around, **I ended up making a table for that section and made the link there**.  I made it look good, but It'd be nice to know the answer for situations where making a new inline VF page is too much.